# Convert Raster to ASCII fundamentally changes my raster layer

Tags: raster, ascii, esri-ascii-raster, maxent

I'm a grad student with experience in GIS but not advanced by any means. Using ArcMap 10.2.2 on our lab's computers. I'm trying to prep environmental variable layers as ASCII layers to analyze using Maxent modeling using the raster to ASCII tool. However, every time I do, it fundamentally changes the values of my layers (Pictures attached, showing the differences between my raster, the original ASCII, and the ASCII when trying 10.8.2). I thought maybe it was just an issue of the upper and lower values, but visually the map has completely changed.

So far I've tried using my advisor's computer (with 10.8.2) and exporting the ASCIIs to my map, other methods of extracting the data before converting, converting to integer type, and also scaling up the original raster data with the raster calculator (multiplied by 1,000,000) but even before scaling back down, the ASCII shows the same incorrect values, just times 1,000,000. I should add that the symbology for all of these layers is identical, as is the raster info.

The only support I can find for doing this in GIS online basically says this is no longer an issue (I guess because of an update) or involves programs I don't know (coding in Java). Does anyone have an idea of how I can solve this in ArcMap and get the raster to ASCII to convert properly?

ArcMap 10.8.2 version

[image]

Original ASCII file

[image]

Original raster file

[image]

https://imgur.com/a/kiakTpf < link to pictures from each layer

Comment: Run calculate statistics tool on the output. Also have you used the info tool and returned the pixel value from all 3 layers in a few random locations? If they are all the same, what you expect then the issue is with the renderer not populating with the full range of values, hence calculate statistics.

Comment: Please use the editor to include the images in your Question body. You are ***much*** less likely to get answers if you force anyone who wants to help to follow an unknown link.